# Будет ли PHP-функция file_get_contents соединяться с последующими IP в списке резолвинга?

Tags: php, сокет, сеть, ip, dns

Если одно доменное имя резолвится в список IP, будет ли PHP-функция `file_get_contents()` соединяться с следующими IP, если не доступен первый?

Если поведение функции согласуется со стандартом, то будьте добры ссылку на оный.

Comment: Если я правильно понял то доменое имя резолвит сервер dns с ip а не браузер функция и т.д. так причём тут file_get_contents()?

Comment: если правильно настроен днс то да) А так file_get_contents() не имеет к этому отношения.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не будет. Установлено экспериментальным путем.

### Рассуждение:

добавление нескольких A записей для одного имени это реализация простейшего механизма балансировки [round-robin](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS). Одним из недостатков которого считается, что при недоступности одной ноды - запросы, отправленные на нее, не будут выполненные и это приведет к частичной недоступности ресурса. т.е. алгоритм подходит для распределения нагрузки, но не для повышения доступности. Тем не менее, это не означает, что конкретно взятый клиент (php) не может реализовать свой механизм обхода альтернативных адресов.

### Поиски:

Документация php ничего об этом не говорит. в документации есть функция `gethostbynamel()`, которая возвращает список, а значит может быть в php это реализовано.
В стандартах RFC тоже при беглом поиске ничего не нашел.
В исходниках C от php также поискал, но ничего похожего на реализацию обхода не нашел.
т.к. все это не означает, что этого нет - решил сделать эксперимент

### Эксперимент

добавил к одной нормальной записи две не нормальные (A 1.1.1.1 и A 8.8.8.8).
Затем реализовал вызов file_get_contents, после чего убедился, что php версии 7.0.15 совершеннно точно получает контент только на каждый 3-ий запрос.
Если была опция, меняющая такое поведение, она была бы [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/context.php) описана...

### Возможна реализация

полагаю, что автор вопроса может реализовать свою обертку функции с необходимым ему поведением, используя вместо хоста IP адреса, полученные из `gethostbynamel`,